# Security in a Javascript based app -refreshing a users hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm developing an hybrid mobile app using HTML/CSS/JS, I'm going over security with login information, the system I have set up creates an hash after a user logs in, this hash has a time limit and is set via localStorage

Essentially, I would have something like this is localstorage:

```
hash
5f4a09cfec2a6d8f306eecb3844e33e9
hash_expiration
1373012945
password
*encryted user password*
```

This hash is sent to my server for validation in the header of all my AJAX requests (accompanied by the user id for database matching)

I'm mostly opening this topic to discuss best practices on how to deal with recreating hash keys, I need to figure out a way to refresh a users hash key.

Considering my experience with AJAX and JS is still rather limited, I thought about using the AJAX setup to check for a new hash, like so:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        var time = new Date().getTime(); //unix time
        var hash_time = localStorage.getItem("hash_expiration");
        if(time>hash_time){
            //ajax request to fetch new hash, async: false to make sure this completes before continuing with other AJAX calls
        }
    }
});
```

I would send the user id and his encrypted password to verify him and return a new hash.

Should I be sending AJAX requests in the ajaxSetup's beforeSend? How would this conflict with other beforeSends across my application?

Answer (score 1):

Basicallly on the clients side you shouldnt have anything except hash. On the server side this hash must be associated with user it belongs to, expire time and anything else you need.

Send this hash with each request, and on server side validate it. When it expires you have to send (server) appropriate headers like 401 - Unauthorized. Client have to understand that response and try to exchange hash to new one. And finally when client gets new valid hash it can resume sending requests.

... and you shouldnt check expire time at client, this job for server.

thanks.

Comment: I would need to listen to all ajax requests and check for a 401 - Unauthorized, if my request gets a 401 - Unauthorized I need to send a new request for a new hash, meanwhile my user gets an error because of the 401 - Unauthorized.

Hmm..

Comment: this process have to be made behind the scene, user should not see errors. Dont forget - browser console is only for you - for developer.

Comment: What I am saying is, imagine a user click to a page, I check the hash and it's wrong, the user needs a new hash - so I send a request for a new hash, but the user has already clicked that page, but since his hash was invalid on the time of that click - I don't allow him in.

Comment: 1. User clicks the link

2. Server receives the hash (from cookies for instance)

3. Server checks hash

4. If hash expired, try to renew it

5. If renew failed - redirect to login page

6. If renew succeed - procceed with page rendering